# fetchAssetCollectionsWithType to only retrieve videos

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, photosframework

I am working on making a custom Gallery view in iOS 
for that I am using the Photos Framework that so far works great 
one thing that I can't get it to work is fetch the result to only return VIDEOS

I tried that 
`let result = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Moment, subtype: .SmartAlbumVideos, options: nil)`
but it's still retrieving images I wonder is the syntax if wrong

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the answer of my question 
Basically I needed to use a predicate this is basically saying retrieve assets where the mediatype is video and also sort it by creationDate

```
let allVideosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
allVideosOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaType.Video.rawValue)
allVideosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
videos = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithOptions(allVideosOptions)
```

Comment: what if i have to add videos from my camera roll only in the same code ??

Answer (score 0):

Here are objective-c codes.

```
PHFetchOptions* fetchOptions;

// all photos
fetchOptions = [[PHFetchOptions alloc] init];
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
if( self.bOnlyVideo == YES ) {
    fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeVideo];
} else if( self.bOnlyPhoto == YES ) {
    fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];
}
self.allPhotos = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:fetchOptions];
[fetchOptions release], fetchOptions = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it with Swift 5.x:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: options)
```